# How to use Socket.io with Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, socket.io, ember-cli

I have been trying to setup the Socket.IO client in one of my initializers but cannot work out how to do it.

All the documentation assumes you are not using ES6 modules and that you are setting up the socket elsewhere in your app.

This is what I have so far:

```
/* Socket Initaializer */
var Initaializer = {
    name: 'Socket',
    initialize: function(Container, App) {

        App.deferReadiness();

        /* Open Socket.IO Connection Here And Then... */

        App.advanceReadiness();

    }
};

/* Export */
export default Initaializer;
```

After this initializer I run another initializer which handles the session/cookies.
I need the Socket connection to be open before this so I can send the cookie to the API to find either an expired/active session or (create a new one) and then return a token.

If someone can either point me to some code samples or even documentation that is relevant to Ember-CLI that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add a `before` key to your initializer, and name the service you want it to execute before:

```
/* Socket Initaializer */
var Initaializer = {
    name: 'Socket',
    before: 'Session', // another service named `Session`
    initialize: function(Container, App) {
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I am currently doing. But it how do I stop the initialiser from finishing before it moves on to the next one?

Comment: I think you'd have to use `deferReadiness` like in your post. Why isn't that working?

Comment: Because the deferReadiness is used in the Session initialiser to continue loading the app when the session has been created. I can only call the defer and advance function set once.

Comment: Why don't you use the `socket` service in your `session` initializer to check for a session?

Comment: This would be a solution. How can I access a service from an initialiser?

Comment: Should be able to use `lookup` on the container

Comment: you can call defer and advance unlimited times.

Comment: So is this actually the solution or is there more to the solution than this?